# How to get a segment of "member.activity" and how to send custom status' (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My whois command is meant to send what the specified user's activity but instead it gives a long reply.  I want it to send the `activity type` and `name`. Also is there a way for the bot to send a person's custom status
Code:

```
    whois_embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color = 0x00ceea)
    whois_embed.add_field(name = "Activity", value = member.activity, inline = False)

    await ctx.send(embed = whois_embed)
```

What the bot sends:

```
Activity
<Activity type=<ActivityType.watching: 3> name='over 3 servers' url=None details=None application_id=None session_id=None emoji=None>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look at the attributes like [declared in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Activity).

To get the name of the activity use

```py
activityName = member.activity.name
```

And to get the type use

```py
activityType = member.activity.type
```

But since `member.activity.type` is not a string, it will print as something like `ActivityType.custom`. You could use a `dict` or something to convert it to a string though.

---

```py
whois_embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color = 0x00ceea)
whois_embed.add_field(name = "Activity", value = member.activity.name, inline = False)

await ctx.send(embed = whois_embed)
```

Comment: the thing is, it doesn't work for both custom status' and watching/playing status'